# AVPlayerViewController slide down menu in tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, tvos9.1

The AVPlayerViewController in tvOS automatically adds the audio menu pictured on a downswipe. How do I add another tab bar item to this menu? I can't seem to figure out how to reach it in code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide title, description, content rating, and an artwork image by setting the externalMetadata property of the AVPlayerItem with an array of AVMetadataItems. The data will then show up in the info panel.

You can also manage chapter markers in a similar way by setting the navigationMarkerGroups property.

Here is a link to more information:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/62104#62104

Comment: Can you add custom actions? Like additional options you might want to toggle on and off?